# Microstack Ussuri does not restart or reboot properly

Tags: 20.04, snap, openstack

I had previously installed Microstack Stein on my Ubuntu 20.04.1 desktop, but the OpenStack CLI never worked properly. So I reinstalled with the latest Microstack snap, Ussuri. The good news is that the OpenStack CLI works properly on Microstack Ussuri. The bad news is that unlike Microstack Stein, Microstack Ussuri does not restart or reboot properly. The symptoms are that several OpenStack services, such as Cinder and Horizon, refuse to initialize when they are restarted or the computer is rebooted; as a result, OpenStack is unusable and the Horizon Dashboard does not display.

In short, Microstack Ussuri only seems to work properly right after the install, not when the machine is rebooted or even when the individual OpenStack services are restarted. And I reboot it a lot because I dual boot with Windows. Is a fix envisioned for Ussuri, or will I have to wait for Microstack Victoria?

Comment: And how would I report this bug to the Canonical Microstack developers?

Comment: If you believe this is a **bug**, then it is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) on AskUbuntu, and you should file a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)